# What does the Sorceress's Hat do?

Tags: candy-box-2

If you go to the Sorceress' Hut, you can click on her hat. She then offers to sell it to you for 1,000,000,000 lollipops. What does it do?

Comment: "it will enhance the effects of your spells and potions" though i cannot explain what the actual enhancements are

Comment: The hat enhances potion and spell effects.

Comment: Turns out fireballs are also bigger.

Answer (score 3):

The Sorceress Hat enhances the effects of your spells and potions. The only effect I have seen so far is to double the amount healed by the health potion, although I am currently experimenting to determine the effects on other potions/spells.

Effects discovered:
Healing potion: Increases amount healed from 100 -> 200
Black Demons: Increases damage from 750 -> 1200
Anti-gravity potion: Increases flight time by a factor of ~1.5